# Why is my Keras prediction always close to 100% for one image class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am using Keras (on top of TF 2.3) to train an image classifier. In some cases I have more than two classes, but often there are just two classes (either "good" or "bad"). I am using the `tensorflow.keras.applications.VGG16` class as base model with a custom classifier on top, like this:

```py
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(self.image_size, self.image_size, 3), name="model_input")
base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer)
model_head = base_model.output
model_head = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(model_head)
model_head = layers.Flatten()(model_head)
model_head = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(model_head)
model_head = layers.Dropout(0.5)(model_head)
model_head = layers.Dense(len(self.image_classes), activation="softmax")(model_head)
```

As you can see in the last (output) layer I am using a `softmax` activation function. Then I compile the whole model with the `categorical_crossentropy` loss function and train with one-hot-encoded image data (labels).

All in all the model performs quite well, I am happy with the results, I achieve over 99% test and validation accuracy with our data set. There is one thing I don't understand though:

When I call `predict()` on the Keras model and look at the prediction results, then these are always either 0 or 1 (or at least very, very close to that, like 0.000001 and 0.999999). So my classifier seems to be quite sure whether an image belongs to either class "good" or "bad" (for example, if I am using only two classes). I was under the assumption, however, that usually these predictions are not that clear, more in terms of *"the model thinks with a probability of 80% that this image belongs to class A"* - but as said in my case it's always 100% sure.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: This is a common research problem with neural networks, that they make overconfident predictions, it is not a problem related to Keras or to programming even.

Answer (score 0):

Your two classes might be very much distinguishable. Try predicting with images having a few common features.

Comment: No, in our data set these images of both classes look nearly the same.

Comment: Just try following two steps: 1) Remove 'AveragePooling2D()' & use directly 'Flatten()'. 2) Use 'BatchNormalization()'. Then please let me know the result.

Comment: I removed the `AveragePooling2D` layer and start directly with `Flatten`, as you have suggested. However, when I then call `set_weights()` on that model to load the pre-trained weights from disk, I get the following error: "ValueError: Layer weight shape (25088, 256) not compatible with provided weight shape (512, 256)". Any idea how I can solve htis?

Comment: You have to find new 'weights' again, as you have changed the network, so earlier weight-file won't work. So re-train the network.